# Calculating derivative of a radial function: am I doing it right?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, harmonic-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ be such that $f$ only depends on the distance from the origin, that is, $f=f(r)$ where $r = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$.

I am trying to calculate $\Delta f$.

> Could someone please tell me if this is right?

My work:

First, I calculated the derivative of $r$ with resepct to one variable:

$$ {\partial r \over \partial x_i} = {1\over 2}\cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot 2x_i = x_i r$$

Then I calculated the first partial derivative:

$$ {\partial f \over \partial x_i}f(r) = {\partial r\over \partial x_i}{\partial f\over \partial r} = x_i r f_r$$

and then the second partial derivative:

$$ {\partial^2 f \over \partial x_i^2}f(r) = {\partial \over \partial x_i}x_i r f_r = {\partial \over \partial x_i}(x_i r)\cdot f_r + x_i r \cdot {\partial \over \partial x_i} f_r = r + x_i^2 rf_r + (x_ir)^2f_{rr}$$

Then

$$ \Delta f = \sum_{i=1}^n {\partial^2 f\over \partial x_i^2} = nr + r^3f_r + r^4f_{rr}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your first calculation:
$$
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\Bigr)^{-{1\over 2}}\cdot 2x_i = \frac{x_i }{r}.
$$